# How to use pivot_wider while passing unkown number of variables to a function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

Building on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778109/handling-a-missing-string-value-to-a-function-when-using-group-by-in-dplyr), I wanted to be able to reference a column using pivot_wider but am unclear of the syntax.

**Reproducible example**

For example, let's say we wanted to created a function that gave us the equivalent output of the following, but with a variable number inputs to group_by:

```
# String inputs
grp1 <- "cyl"
grp2 <- "carb"

# 2 variables input
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(.data[[grp1]], .data[[grp2]]) %>% 
  summarize(mean_hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(., names_from = .data[[grp1]], values_from = mean_hp)

    # A tibble: 6 x 4
   carb   `4`   `6`   `8`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  77.4  108.   NA 
2     2  87     NA   162.
3     4  NA    116.  234 
4     6  NA    175    NA 
5     3  NA     NA   180 
6     8  NA     NA   335
```

To get a variable number of inputs (i.e., grp1 only, grp1, grp2, and grp 3), the previous question pointed out that the solution was to use ellipses like so:

```
# String inputs
grp1 <- "cyl"
grp2 <- "carb"

# Create simple function
car_fx <- function(df, ...) {
  output <- df %>% 
    group_by_at(c(...)) %>% 
    summarize(mean_hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE))
}

# Works with variable number of inputs
(car_fx(mtcars, grp1, grp2))
(car_fx(mtcars, grp1))
```

In my real function, I also wanted to pivot the data and do so typically with the first input variable (e.g., grp1) as above in the pivot_wider example.  How would I pivot_wider that using the ellipse solution to a variable number of inputs?  Specifically, how would I do this with only 1 variable input and how would I do this with 2 variables input and reference the 2nd variable by which to pivot?  I tried this as a way to reference the first variable, but it did not work:

```
# Doesn't work
car_fx <- function(df, ...) {
  output <- df %>% 
    group_by_at(c(...)) %>% 
    summarize(mean_hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(., names_from = names(.[[1]]), values_from = mean_hp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
car_fx <- function(df, ...) {
  output <- df %>% 
    group_by_at(c(...)) %>% 
    summarize(mean_hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(., names_from = c(...)[1], values_from = mean_hp)
    output
}
```

You can change the [1] to your taste, and if you need specific behaviour around say 3 groups, welcome to if else hell, good luck

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, please consider up voting as well